How to utilize FromBody and FromRoute in the same model with model binding
I am trying to utilize FromRoute for one property of a model and FromBody for the remaining items as the API is accepting JSON. My code is as follows:
    [HttpPost("{state_id}/StateContact")]
    [Authorize]
    [OktaAllowedRoles(["arms-dmcp-user", "arms-oact-user", "arms-approver"])]
    [EnableRateLimiting("api")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddStateContact([FromBody] AddStateContactDTO addStateContactDTO)
    {
        try
        {
            return Ok(addStateContactDTO);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return Ok(ex);
        } 
    }

and my model is as follows:
    public class AddStateContactDTO 
{
    [FromRoute(Name = "state_id")]
    public required int StateId {get; set;}

    [ModelBinder(Name = "first_name")]
    public string? FirstName {get; set;}

    [ModelBinder(Name = "last_name")]
    public string? LastName {get; set;}

    [ModelBinder(Name = "email_address")]
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "The Email address submitted is not a valid e-mail address.")]
    public required string EmailAddress {get; set;}
}

My request looks as follows:
  const submitAddNewStateContact = () => {
if(addStateContactValid.value) {
  const json = {
    first_name : newStateContactFirstNameModel.value,
    last_name : newStateContactLastNameModel.value,
    email_address : newStateContactEmailAddressModel.value
  }

  let form = new FormData();
  form.append('first_name' , JSON.stringify(newStateContactFirstNameModel.value))
  form.append('last_name' , JSON.stringify(newStateContactLastNameModel.value))
  form.append('email_address' , JSON.stringify(newStateContactEmailAddressModel.value))

  api.post('/states/'+stateModel.value!.state_id+'/StateContact', json, config).then(response => {})
}

}
POST with the json data results in the following error:
{
"type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.5.1",
"title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
"status": 400,
"errors": {
    "$": [
        "The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.",
        "The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.",
        "The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0."
    ],
    "email_address": [
        "The EmailAddress field is required."
    ]
},
"traceId": "00-bcbe8b4460713f9266f5d6bbc15b940a-1746bfdbf5ba5213-00"

}
However, If I were to turn my model into this:
        [HttpPost("{state_id}/StateContact")]
    [Authorize]
    [OktaAllowedRoles(["arms-dmcp-user", "arms-oact-user", "arms-approver"])]
    [EnableRateLimiting("api")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddStateContact([FromForm] AddStateContactDTO addStateContactDTO)
    {
        try
        {
            return Ok(addStateContactDTO);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return Ok(ex);
        } 
    }

    public class AddStateContactDTO 
{
    [FromRoute(Name = "state_id")]
    public int StateId {get; set;}

    [ModelBinder(Name = "first_name")]
    public string? FirstName {get; set;}

    [ModelBinder(Name = "last_name")]
    public string? LastName {get; set;}

    [ModelBinder(Name = "email_address")]
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "The Email address submitted is not a valid e-mail address.")]
    public required string EmailAddress {get; set;}
}

So basically switch to using FromForm and POSTing form data then everything binds as it should. However, I would like the option to send data as json without sending form data and also using FromRoute for some parameters of the model but this does not seem possible. Is this a bug or just not possible to use FromRoute and FromBody together?

Why not public async Task<IActionResult> AddStateContact([FromRoute(Name = "state_id")] int StateId, [FromBody] AddStateContactDTO addStateContactDTO)? And remove the StateId property from the AddStateContactDTO class. Otherwise, you should post the StateId in the request body. Note that you can't use the [FromBody] attribute multiple times.

Its just strange that if I were to put     public async Task AddStateContact([FromBody] AddStateContactDTO addStateContactDTO) it fails to validate as its not using the Route parameter StateId when deserializing abut if I do  public async Task AddStateContact([FromForm] AddStateContactDTO addStateContactDTO) it will utilize the Route parameter StateId when binding. This just seems inconsistent. I prefer to use the parent model rather than laying out all the items of the model as you have. This just seems like a bug but I am unsure if I am just doing this wrong

I believe this is the default behavior for FromBody attribute.

If FromForm is more flexible in this sense since you do not have to define it manually as shown in your answer below, would you lean towards using it over frombody? Any well known web apis require data to come in fromform vs frombody/json?

Hmmm, it is opinion-based. As I know FromForm or passing the data as form-data, will make it complex when you have nested object or array. You need to generate the key pair like: "obj.nested_field" or "array[0].field" when building the FormData. And with FromBody you can just post the JSON body directly.

personally I find it confusing when a POST reads any query params from the URL.  If you are using JSON, you can simply bind everything to one class object.  That'll allow for as complex an array as you need.  When sending FormData() javascript object, you should be aware that headers and type are automatically set.  (It'll be just like a standard form POST.)  ASP.NET's "FromBody" tries to infer the type from the body and won't expect GET-like query params... since a GET has no body.

@yong shun - my issue is there is some instances in my web api I have to send files and data in one request and you ultimately have to use fromform for file upload which creates some consistency on my end of some endpoints using frombody and json and some using fromform. So I am at a internal conflict of consistency and usability (fromform file upload being more efficient). SO in this scenario I am trying to test out the frombody but fromform seems to be more flexible with the fromroute parameters.

According to [FromBody] attribute:

When [FromBody] is applied to a complex type parameter, any binding source attributes applied to its properties are ignored.
Input formatters read only the body and don't understand binding source attributes.
Don't apply [FromBody] to more than one parameter per action method. Once the request stream is read by an input formatter, it's no longer available to be read again for binding other [FromBody] parameters.

Thus, you have to change the action method signature to:
public async Task<IActionResult> AddStateContact([FromRoute(Name = "state_id")] int stateId, [FromBody] AddStateContactDTO addStateContactDTO)
{
    addStateContactDTO.StateId = stateId;

    ...
}

public class AddStateContactDTO 
{
    public int StateId {get; set;}

    [ModelBinder(Name = "first_name")]
    public string? FirstName {get; set;}

    [ModelBinder(Name = "last_name")]
    public string? LastName {get; set;}

    [ModelBinder(Name = "email_address")]
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "The Email address submitted is not a valid e-mail address.")]
    public required string EmailAddress {get; set;}
}


Updated
You may look for a Custom Model Binder to help construct the model data before executing the action.
In the custom model binder, it should:

Extract the "state_id" from the route.

Read and deserialize the request body as model.

Bind the extracted "state_id" and assign to the model.


[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(StateIdModelBinder))]
public class AddStateContactDTO
{
    ...
}

public class StateIdModelBinder : IModelBinder
{

    public StateIdModelBinder()
    {

    }

    public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        var request = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var stateIdString = request.RouteValues["state_id"]?.ToString();

        using var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body);
        var body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        var model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AddStateContactDTO>(body, new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.SnakeCaseLower
        });

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(stateIdString))
        {
            int stateId = Convert.ToInt32(stateIdString);

            model.StateId = stateId;
        }

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
    }
}


I would add the [JsonIgnore] attribute to the StateId in the AddStateContactDTO otherwise it will be visibile in the request body too.

@ peppermintology the JsonIgnore does allow the controller action to continue as the required field which is not in the deserialized json is ignored. However, when using [FromBody] still does not bind the FromRoute parameter despite making it to the deserialized state.

@Yong Shun thank you for the answer. Please see my edit above for applying the FromBody once and how it imitates the FromForm syntax and implementation that works.

You can't mix the various attributes in nested objects, but you can use them on the same (maybe nested level). Due to this, you have two approaches you can use:

Individual parameters in method call:

public async Task<IActionResult> AddStateContact(
    [FromRoute(Name = "state_id"] int stateId,
    [FromBody] AddStateContactDto addStateContactDto)


Individual properties in parameter complex object:

//                  No attributes used here !!! 
public async Task<IActionResult> AddStateContact(AddStateContactDto addStateContactDto)

public class AddStateContactDto
{
    [FromRoute(Name = "state_id")]
    public int StateId { get; set; }

    [FromBody]
    public AddStateContactDetailsDto Details { get; set; }
}


In approach 1 do you have to manually set state_id in the AddStateContactDto equal to stateId parameter in the body of the action? Also, in option 2 you put no attributes here but don't I still need  [HttpPost("{state_id}/StateContact")] attribute?

In approach 1 you have to manually combine those two values somehow. If you have a class that has both parameters as property or you manually set the first value in a property of the second paramter is up to you.

In approach 2 you don't have to apply any attributes on the method level. You apply all attributes in the destination class properties. Only then this approach works. If you mix the levels where you apply the attributes, it won't work.

Oh i see you nested that object into another so you could apply one tag to each object/property. Ughh I hate that FromBody does not act in a similar manner to FromRoute. I found a github request on this. Seems to be a bug https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/45392 unless I am misreading this. Seems very similar to my situation.
